# Can you include `gets.chomp` in a variable with a prompt?

Tags: ruby

I am wondering if it is possible to include both a prompt character and gets.chomp in a variable. I can do:

```
prompt = "> "
puts prompt
input = gets.chomp
```

but is there a way to put both of them in a single `prompt` variable so that I don't need to type `input = gets.chomp` when I type `puts prompt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap them in a method:

```
def ask_for_input
  prompt = "> "
  puts prompt
  gets.chomp
end


input = ask_for_input # both prints a prompt and reads input
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to always use the highline gem

```
require 'highline/import'
name = ask "whats your name"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create your own `gets` method in the Kernel module :

```
module Kernel
  def my_gets
    gets.chomp
  end
end

input = my_gets

print(input)
```